# How do i phrase vert.x log in logstash

Tags: logstash

I have log file with vert.x logs that i want to show in Kibana. How do i phrase following log,  I want to phrase  only IP, Request and Response time.

Here is my sample log.

```
 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-7] 2016-09-27T07:13:53.263Z INFO [com.term.local.rest.server.Server]  SUCCESS RESPONSE : 1.get.mydata, remoteIp : 192.168.1.1, processing time : 115
```

From this log i want only  following information to visualise in Kibana

SUCCESS RESPONSE : 1.get.mydata, remoteIp : 192.168.1.1, processing time : 115

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grok {
    match => {
        "message" => [
            "%{GREEDYDATA}SUCCESS RESPONSE : %{NOTSPACE:response}, remoteIp : %{IP:remoteip}, processing time : %{INT:proceesingTime}"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: To help you next time you need to work on a grok filter: [grok filter tester](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result), [grok filter documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) and [grok patterns](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns).